# Formato de celda en xlsx React

Tags: json, reactjs, npm, simplexlsx

Estoy exportando un json a un libro de Excel usando la librería XLSX de React y necesito darle formato a las celdas, por ejemplo, color a los encabezados y que se autoajuste al contenido.

Les dejo mi código que exporta el json al libro de Excel:

```
const exportExcel = () => {
    let valuesToExport = objectsFromCols();
    const worksheet = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(valuesToExport);
    const workbook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = xlsx.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, dt.props.exportFilename);
}

const saveAsExcelFile = (buffer: any, fileName: string): void => {
        let EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
        let EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';
        const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
            type: EXCEL_TYPE
        });
        saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
}
```

Muchas gracias por las respuestas de antemano.

Comment: ¿puedes mencionar cuál librería específica estás usando para esto? ni idea cual pueda ser la librería XLSX de React

Comment: Es XLSX, así tal cual. https://docs.sheetjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La librería XLSX no soporta estilos en la versión de comunidad, únicamente en su versión PRO de pago.